# SQL function - setting the date argument to have a null default breaks the function

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eventidswithinradius(
    lat double precision,
    lng double precision,
    radius double precision DEFAULT 10000.0)
  RETURNS SETOF bigint AS
$BODY$
  SELECT event.event_id 
  FROM event 
  JOIN location l USING (location_id)  
  WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(lat, lng), 
  CASE WHEN radius > 100000.0 OR radius < 1 THEN 10000.0 ELSE radius END
  ) @> ll_to_earth(l.latitude, l.longitude);
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

And I wanted to expand it with two optional parameters of event `start_date` and `end_date` whose default argument values would be `NULL`. So I wrote this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eventidswithinradius1(
    lat double precision,
    lng double precision,
    radius double precision DEFAULT 10000.0,
    e_start_date date DEFAULT NULL,
    e_end_date date DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURNS SETOF bigint AS
$BODY$
  SELECT event.event_id 
  FROM event 
  JOIN location l USING (location_id)  
  WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(lat, lng), 
  CASE WHEN radius > 100000.0 OR radius < 1 THEN 10000.0 ELSE radius END
  ) @> ll_to_earth(l.latitude, l.longitude);
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

NOTE: I only added the two arguments and I'm not using them yet.

However now when I run both functions with the same parameters ie.:

```
SELECT * FROM eventidswithinradius(40.1234, 15.2131, 100000.0);
SELECT * FROM eventidswithinradius1(40.1234, 15.2131, 100000.0);
```

Only the first one returns any data. The second one returns an empty table.

I've also tried adding a single test `varchar` argument also with `DEFAULT NULL` instead of two dates, and the same thing occurred.

Can anyone tell me what is happening here? I thought thought that PostgreSQL doesn't support multiple default arguments, however checking the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-PARAMETER-DEFAULTS) I've found that `Functions can be declared with default values for some or all input arguments.` so this should clearly work.

Upon further investigation, adding the date argument without `DEFAULT` works so I am to assume that NULL is not allowed to be the default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note of the following http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createfunction.html:

> **CALLED ON NULL INPUT**, **RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT**, **STRICT**
>
> CALLED ON NULL INPUT (the default) indicates that the function will be called
>   normally when some of its arguments are null. It is then the function
>   author's responsibility to check for null values if necessary and
>   respond appropriately.
>
> RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT or STRICT indicates that the function
>   always returns null whenever any of its arguments are null. If this
>   parameter is specified, the function is not executed when there are
>   null arguments; instead a null result is assumed automatically.

So in your case replace **STRICT** with **CALLED ON NULL INPUT** and perform null-checks yourself inside the function.

Comment: That's it! I focused on the `DEFAULT` parameters doc instead of looking up `CREATE FUNCTION`. Thanks for the help.